# Observable - map / concat

Tags: typescript, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am new to Observables.  I have the following Effect.

I would like the PositionUpdateAction or PositionFailedAction to be dispatched prior to the dispatch of the SunriseSunsetAction.

What is occurring is I get the result of getCurrentPosition() passed into the last map in the result variable and the SunriseSunsetAction is dispatched.  Neither the PositionUpdateAction or PositionFailedAction are dispatched.

I assume I would want to use concat in someway.  I have been trying various things without success.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Effect()
  position$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ActionType.GetPosition),
    mergeMap(() =>
      fromPromise(this.geo.getCurrentPosition()).pipe(
        map(value => new UiActions.PositionUpdateAction(value)),
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(new UiActions.PositionFailedAction(err));
        })
      ).map(result =>
        new UiActions.SunriseSunsetAction(this.sun.calculateSunriseSunsetWindows(result.payload.lat, result.payload.long))
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: So if if fails you want to see both the `PositionFailedAction` and the `SunriseSunsetAction`?

Comment: actually good point, if it fails I would not want to have the SunriseSunsetAction dispatched

Comment: OK, I reordered the operators in my answer so that the catch is after the second action is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving a generic solution to what I understand your problem to be. The general scenario is that you have some operation and you want to use the result to perform another operation. In the end you want the result of both to be emitted.

In your specific scenario the first operation is some request and the second is mapping to another action.

The solution is to use `*Map(...)` (`switchMap`, `mergeMap`, ...) to use the result of the first operation to perform the second. Rather than directly returning the observable from the second you can use `concat` to emit both results in the order of your choosing. Here is a generic example:

```js
const { of, concat } = rxjs;
const { flatMap } = rxjs.operators;

of(1).pipe(
  flatMap((x) => concat(of(x), of(2)))
).subscribe((x) => { console.log(x); })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.1.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

So your code might look something like this:

```
@Effect()
position$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionType.GetPosition),
  mergeMap(() =>
    fromPromise(this.geo.getCurrentPosition()).pipe(
      map(value => new UiActions.PositionUpdateAction(value)),
      flatMap((x) => concat(
        of(x),
        new UiActions.SunriseSunsetAction(this.sun.calculateSunriseSunsetWindows(result.payload.lat, result.payload.long))
      )),
      catchError((err) => {
        return of(new UiActions.PositionFailedAction(err));
      })
    )
  )
);
```

Since you are using effects, another solution would be to setup another effect to listen for the `PositionUpdateAction` action. Might turn into spaghetti though...

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot!

Comment: @brent Great! Well if it answered your question then you can check the checkmark next to the answer to accept it so that others know that it answers your question. If not then let me know if you need further help.